# Is there a formula that Compute ($\sin x $) with Approximation.??

Tags: trigonometry

We know that :

$$\sin 30^\circ = \frac{1}{2}=0.50$$

$$\sin 45^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\simeq 0.707$$

$$\sin 60^\circ= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\simeq 1.73$$

$$\vdots$$

Is there a formula that Compute ($\sin x $) with Approximation.??

$$\sin 1^\circ\simeq?$$

$$\sin 2^\circ \simeq?$$

$$\sin 3^\circ \simeq?$$

$$\vdots$$

Comment: What you wrote is incorrect.  $\sin 30\ne\frac12$.  Do you mean $\sin 30^\circ$?

Comment: Have you considered Taylor Series approximation? This might be helpful: http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf

Comment: Taylor series are what you're looking for. Without knowing the requisite calculus, suffice to say that $\sin(x)\approx x-x^3/6$, if $x$ is in radians and is small (i.e. near 0 radians).

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor Series:

$$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} + ... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}$$

Note you have to convert to radians:

$$\theta^\circ=\frac\pi{180}\theta\text{ radians}$$

Comment: N0 . i want  Quick and approximate calculation !!!!

Comment: @Simple Art sorry I skip to write this. Thank u.

Comment: @zahraafshar what do you mean?  The above is the quickest way to approximate sine, just take, say, the first three terms and you will get extremely good estimates for your given angles.

Comment: @zahraafshar What's not quick and simple here? Taking the first two or three terms is good enough for almost any application.

Comment: As Simple Art and Ducky already mentioned it is the quickest way.

Answer (score 1):

Try bhaskara's sine approximation formula :
$$
\sin x^\circ = \frac {4x(180-x)}{40500-x(180-x)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You may find the exact value of any integer degree angle using the sum of angles formula as described [here](http://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/how-do-you-find-exact-values-for-the-sine-of-all-angles-6212).  The value of $\sin(1^\circ)$ is given below, for example.

[image]